# Rewrite matching URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite matching URLs of my website but it's not working for some reason, don't know why...
Here is current URL:

```
example.com/details.php?p=10&text=some-text-is-here
```

want to write like this

```
example.com/post-details/10/some-text-is-here
```

My .htaccess is here

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/details\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /details/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^details/([0-9]+)$ /details.php?id=$1 [L]
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/details\.php\?p=(\d+)&text=(.+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /post-details/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^post-details/(\d+)/(.+)$ /details.php?p=$1&text=$2 [L,NE]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache the test

Comment: Hello, it's not working at all...nothing happen regarding rewriting of url...once I removed these two lines (RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d ) everything starts working perfect but then I got the issue it also rewrite the urls of images available on the page such...original image url=http://example.com/images/download.jpg but remove those conditions then I got this url=http://example.com/torrent-detail/11/images/download.jpg         that's why images not able to load on the same page

Comment: @orichec1000 clear browser cache the test updated rules

Comment: Thank you so much for updating the rule but not change happens still every url on the page including images urls are still being rewritten by .htaccess but this this I need not to remove any line to let it work...url is being written as per requested but problem is everything is being written unfortunately instead of particular url

Comment: @orichec1000 i will exclude images from rules  ok

Comment: I gave you example of images, actually every link on the page is being written in the same format as of browsing url of that page.

Comment: No change occurred, still the same results as before.

Comment: paste your htaccess file

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/details\.php\?id=(\d+)&urlTitle=(.+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /post-details/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^post-details/(\d+)/(.+)$ /details.php?id=$1&urlTitle=$2 [L,NE]

Comment: @orichec1000 images should not be captured by these rules at all , unless it starting with post-details

Comment: is it possible, we can only rewrite browsing url of the page instead of rewriting every url in the page?

Comment: @orichec1000 that really what happened , these rules only for request contain either details.php or post-details unless there are files originally starting with these

Comment: so what do you think, what should I do now to make it possible?